# How from Gitlab inject parameter to testcafe commandline

Tags: testing, parameters, gitlab, automated-tests, testcafe

For example I have command '- /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium:headless tests/ -F "Smoke*"  --skip-js-errors'
But I want to set in Gitlab variable which kind of test to run (Smoke, regression or just test name instead hardcoded command -F "Smoke*") and testcafe get this variable to run tests . How to do this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [grouped jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#group-jobs-in-a-pipeline) in a pipeline, each running a subset of tests (Smoke, regression, etc). Also, by doing so, you can get advantage of parallel execution. If you don't like a hardcoding part of a test suite, which you want to run in a script, you can add custom environment variables to your build environment. Follow the Gitlab documentation: [Create a custom variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#create-a-custom-variable-in-gitlab-ciyml).

Comment: I know how to add variables on GitLab, but I don't know how to send command like - /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh chromium:headless tests/ -F "some variable from GitLab" --skip-js-errors

Comment: You can use `$VARIABLE` or `${VARIABLE}` syntax to inject a variable into your command-line script. There is an example in the [Create a custom variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#create-a-custom-variable-in-gitlab-ciyml) article.